# When will Pocket Monsters the Movie: Coco be released outside of Japan?

Tags: pokemon

I am really excited to watch *Pocket Monsters the Movie: Coco* but it seems it's not released outside Japan and also not dubbed in English. So when is this going to happen? Does somebody have any confirmed date or source?

Answer (score 5):

No release date has been confirmed but it's definitely getting a US/UK release. The last official communication (via [twitter](https://twitter.com/Pokemon/status/1334943756823519233)) was that it's mooted for 2021. Note that the overseas title is *Pokémon the Movie: Secrets of the Jungle*, not *Pocket Monsters the Movie: Coco*

> What happens when a human baby is raised by Pokémon? You’ll find out in Pokémon the Movie: Secrets of the Jungle when it releases next year!
>
> <sub><sup>7:32 PM · Dec 4, 2020</sup></sub>

There's also been a trailer released.

**The Mythical Pokémon swings into action in Pokémon the Movie: Secrets of the Jungle—coming in 2021!**

Comment: yes I know about this US/UK release trailer. That's why I am so excited to watch it ASAP.